# How to using memory stream to save image without using save file dialog

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

**How to replace save file dialog by using memory stream ?**

I generate qr code for name and country and member

qr code generated without any problem

but i need to use memory stream to save image of qr  and not use save file dialog

my code as below

```
 using (SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|.jpg", ValidateNames = true })
                    {
                        if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder encoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
                            encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;


                            string encoding = "UserName : " + textBox4.Text + "\r\n" + "Country : " + comboBox3.Text + "\r\n" + "Membership :" + comboBox5.Text;


                            Bitmap bmp = encoder.Encode(encoding);
                            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                            path = sv.FileName;
                            bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        }

                    }
```

**How to replace save file dialog by using memory stream ?**

Comment: Your question makes very little sense in the context of the shown code.  What is it that you believe saving the bitmap to a MemoryStream will achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a Bitmap to a memory stream directly:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```